# Redirect to login page if the user is not authentificated using NextJS and ExpressJS as a backend with axios for binding and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, next.js

i have a problm with this part of the code ,
iam coding a website with NextJS as a frontend and ExpressJS as a backend and MongoDB as a database and i use axios to bind between them so ,
i want to protect the routes from accessing users without login ,
so it must login to acess this routes , if the user try to access to protected route will redirect auto to login page
i try many things to work it up but nothing works ,
i need some help and thanks

this code for App.js for NextJS(front-end)

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import '../public/nprogress.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStart = (url) => {
      console.log(`Loading: ${url}`)
      NProgress.start()
    }
    const handleStop = () => {
      NProgress.done()
    }

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleStop)
    router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleStop)

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleStop)
      router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleStop)
    }
  }, [router])
  return( 
    <>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
   

    </>
  )}

export default MyApp
```

and this code for page home that must be protected from not login users , NextJS(front-end)

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Innovant App" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.PNG" />
      </Head>
      <NavBar />
      <div className={styles.body}>
        <div className={styles.logohome}>
          <div className={styles.logopos}>
              <div className={styles.less_symbol}></div>
              <div className={styles.grater_symbol}></div>

            </div>
              
        </div>
        <p className={styles.p}>The Logo Above is Made in Pure CSS</p>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this code for page login NextJS(front-end)

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import axios from 'axios'
import styles from '../styles/SignIn.module.css'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faUserPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faSignInAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import Link from 'next/link';


const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [messageType, setMessageType] = useState();
  const url = 'http://192.168.1.9:3001/api/login';


  const handleLogin = async (credentials, setSubmitting) => {
    handleMessage(null);

    axios
      .post(url, credentials)
      .then(async (response) => {

        const result = response.data;
        const { status, message, data } = result;
        if (status !== 'SUCCESS') {
          handleMessage(message, status);
        } else {
          try {
            router.push('/home');
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log('error to save data')
          }

        }
        setSubmitting(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        setSubmitting(false);
        handleMessage('An error occurred. Check your network and try again');
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const handleMessage = (message, type = '') => {
    setMessage(message);
    setMessageType(type);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Sign in</title>
        <meta name="description" content="innovant App" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/logo.PNG" />

      </Head>
      <div className={styles.nav1}>
        <div className={styles.main1}>
          <font className={styles.txt2} ><Link href="/" >Sign in</Link></font>
          <font  className={styles.txt1} ><Link href="/register" >Register</Link></font>
        </div>
      </div>

        <NavBar/>

    
      <form name="formone" >
        <div className={styles.body}>
       
          <table className={styles.tab1}>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <div className={styles.verif}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.facheck} icon={faCheck} />
            </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           
            <tr>

              <td className={styles.td2}>
                <Link  href={{pathname: '/register',}}>  
                <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.iconuser} icon={faUserPlus} /></Link>
                 <p className={styles.txt4}><Link href={{pathname: '/register',}} >Register</Link></p>
                <p className={styles.txt5}>Browse and find what you need</p>
              </td>
              <td className={styles.td} >
                <Link href={{pathname: '/',}}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles.iconuser} icon={faSignInAlt} />
                </Link>
                <p className={styles.txt4}><Link href={{pathname: '/',}}>Sign in</Link></p>
                <p className={styles.txt5}>Already have an account then welcome back</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
              if (email == '' || password == '') {
                handleMessage('Please fill in all fields');
                setSubmitting(false);
              } else {
                handleLogin(values, setSubmitting);
              }
            }}
          >
            {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values }) => (
              <div className={styles.inputfield}>
                <input className={styles.input} type="email" placeholder='Email*' value={values.email} onChange={handleChange('email')} required />
                <input className={styles.input} type="password" placeholder='Password*' value={values.password} onChange={handleChange('password')} required />
                <p style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'center' }}>  
            {message}</p>
              
                <button type="submit" className={styles.btnlogin} onClick={handleSubmit}>
                  <p className={styles.txt6}>Submit</p>
                  
                  </button>
                  
              </div>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      </form>

    <Footer/>

    </div>
  )
}
export default Login;
```

and finaly this is the code for API in ExpressJS (Backend)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const User = require("./../model/User");

// Password handler
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//register
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    let { firstname, lastname, email, password, confirmpassword } = req.body;
    firstname = firstname;
    lastname = lastname;
    email = email;
    password = password;
    confirmpassword = confirmpassword;

    if (firstname == "" || lastname == ""|| email == "" || password == "" || confirmpassword == "") {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Empty input fields!",
        });
    } else if (!/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(firstname)) {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Invalid firstname  entered",
        });
    }
        else if (!/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/.test(lastname)) {
            res.json({
                status: "FAILED",
                message: "Invalid lastname  entered",
            });
    } else if (!/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(email)) {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Invalid email entered",
        });
    } else if (password.length < 8) {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Password is too short!",
        });
    } else if (password !== confirmpassword) {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "sec password must be same!",
        });
    } else {
        // Checking if user already exists
        User.find({ email })
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.length) {
                    // A user already exists
                    res.json({
                        status: "FAILED",
                        message: "User with the provided email already exists",
                    });
                } else {
                    // Try to create new user
                    // password handling
                    const saltRounds = 10;
                    bcrypt
                        .hash(password, saltRounds)
                        .then((hashedPassword) => {
                            const newUser = new User({
                                firstname,
                                lastname,
                                email,
                                password: hashedPassword,
                            });

                            newUser
                                .save()
                                .then((result) => {
                                    res.json({
                                        status: "SUCCESS",
                                        message: "Signup successful",
                                        data: result,
                                    });
                                })
                                .catch((err) => {
                                    res.json({
                                        status: "FAILED",
                                        message: "An error occurred while saving user account!",
                                    });
                                });
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            res.json({
                                status: "FAILED",
                                message: "An error occurred while hashing password!",
                            });
                        });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({
                    status: "FAILED",
                    message: "An error occurred while checking for existing user!",
                });
            });
    }
});

// login
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    let { email, password } = req.body;
    email = email;
    password = password;

    if (email == "" || password == "") {
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Empty credentials supplied",
        });
    } else {
        // Check if user exist
        User.find({ email })
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.length) {
                    // User exists

                    const hashedPassword = data[0].password;
                    bcrypt
                        .compare(password, hashedPassword)
                        .then((result) => {
                            if (result) {
                                // Password match
                                res.json({
                                    status: "SUCCESS",
                                    message: "Signin successful",
                                    data: data,
                                });
                            } else {
                                res.json({
                                    status: "FAILED",
                                    message: "Invalid password entered!",
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            res.json({
                                status: "FAILED",
                                message: "An error occurred while comparing passwords",
                            });
                        });
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        status: "FAILED",
                        message: "Invalid credentials entered!",
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                res.json({
                    status: "FAILED",
                    message: "An error occurred while checking for existing user",
                });
            });
    }
});



module.exports = router;
```

Thanks Again for helping me

Comment: I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication, you must use cookie or HTTP only cookies and JWT.please Read this article you will get more ideas how to handle Authentication in backend and frontend. [node-js-express-jwt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-jwt-expressjs)

Comment: But i did the authentification with node express but i only want to protect the route home from users that not authentified , so to access the route home must authentified  do u understand me ? 
Thanks for your helping

Comment: You did but while a user login you should encrypt some data and store in the client cookie and from next you should check if the cookie is available or not the redirection is easy you can use a useEffect like this:                                                                    
useEffect(() => {}
if(!document.coockie){
 router.push('/login')
}
,[])

Comment: and you can use JWT strategy if a user login send a jwt to client for a specific expiration time so you did not implement this method in your backend.

Comment: Ok will try it but can u contact me on linkedIn will better to tok there and thanks , this is my linkedIn profil :    https://www.linkedin.com/in/sfar-hatem-60b009199/        Waiting ur msg thanks again

Comment: No problem I will try to contact you as soon as possible.